# Cannot run Java class files with hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Whenever I am trying to use Java class files as my mapper and/or reducer I am getting the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "MapperTst.class": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

I executed the following command on the terminal:

```
hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar -file /home/hadoop/codes/MapperTst.class -mapper /home/hadoop/codes/MapperTst.class -file /home/hadoop/codes/ReducerTst.class -reducer /home/hadoop/codes/ReducerTst.class  -input gutenberg/* -output gutenberg-outputtstch27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your fully qualified Mapper class name (including the package) is codes.MapperTest and the reducer class name is codes.ReducerTst,

Package your Map and reduce classes into a jar file say /home/hadoop/test.jar
Your command should work if you modify it to :

```
hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar \
   contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar \
   -libjars /home/hadoop/test.jar \
   -mapper codes.MapperTst \
   -reducer codes.ReducerTst \
   -input gutenberg/* -output gutenberg-outputtstch27
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was for me to put the java mapper/reducer/combiner in a specified package. With the default package it won't work. It will give you the error you had.

Answer (score -2):

Streaming is not supposed to work with Java classes. It is supposed to run anything which can be treated as a linux command. Input data will be fed into the input stream and output will be treated as an mapper output.
If you already have mapper class in java - you do not need streaming.